# Almost sure convergence of an algorithm

Tags: probability, probability-theory, pointwise-convergence

You designed an algorithm and you proved that this algorithm converges almost surely. Let's note $X_n$ the value of your algorithm at step $n$, which is a random variable, and $X$ the true converged value. 
Thus, one has:
$\mathbb{P}[\ \lim_{n\to+\infty}X_n = X]\ = 1$

What does it mean concretely? For instance, does it meean that if you run it many times, it may fail to converge as $n$ goes to $+\infty$? What is the difference with pointwise convergence in this context?

Comment: Almost sure convergence means that $$\mathbb P(\{\omega\in\Omega : \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)\}) = 1, $$ i.e. that $X_n\to X$ except possibly on an event with probability zero. Pointwise convergence would mean that $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$, but this concept is rarely useful from a probabilistic standpoint.

Comment: Thank you. But what does it mean for a practical case, such as an algorithm?

Comment: Practically, it means that it will always converge. You can re-do the experiment as many times as you like (even a countably infinite number of times) and it will converge every single time.  Strictly speaking, the probability it converges every time is 1.  Prob 1 convergence is also called "almost sure convergence" and, for all practical purposes, is just as good as "sure convergence" (which seems to be what you are calling "pointwise").  Of course, "convergence" is a concept that deals with $n\rightarrow\infty$, so practically, you cannot simulate an infinite number of steps.

Comment: Note that if $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$ are an infinite sequence of events that satisfy $P[A_i]=1$ for all $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ then $$P[\cap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i] = 1$$

Comment: Thank you very much. It much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a practical example with Strong Law of Large Numbers. You can use the random number generator to create a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables and then compute its mean. If this sequence is long enough, this mean will be close to the true mean of a random variable you used to generate a sequence. Now, imagine you generate many such sequences, over and over again. Almost sure convergence implies that means computed for all these sequences will be close to the true mean. You can, of course, imagine a valid sequence whose mean is quite far from the true mean, but almost sure converges guarantees that probability of such a sequence is 0, i.e., for a large enough sequence size the random number generator will never produce a sequence like that.